# Laravel Translate Notification Email Template According to Notifiable Locale

Tags: laravel

I have a multi language Laravel App where the locale for each user in user table as **locale** column.

At the beginning of each request I set the app locale to the current logged in user's locale:

```
App::setLocale(App::user()->locale);
```

When a user **A** make an event, I send notification (via database and mail) to all other users which may have different locales from user **A**.

Now I am using sync driver for notifications.

I am aware that I can translate the content of the email in `toMail` function. But there are still some labels in the template which I can't control the translation for them. They are translated according to user **A** locale instead of **notifiable** locale.

I published the notification email template:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Which copy notification email template to resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php

In this template there some translations for example:

```
@lang('Whoops!')
@lang('Hello!')
@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser:',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
    ]
) <span class="break-all">[{{ $displayableActionUrl }}]({{ $actionUrl }})</span>
```

I need to pass the notifiable locale to this file in order to translate labels correctly:

```
@lang('Whoops!', [], $notifiableLocale)
@lang('Hello!', [], $notifiableLocale)
```

How can I pass the notifiable locale to that template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the variable straightly in vendor view, as it is rendered by laravel's core libraries. TBH passing locale as variable makes template a bit messy. You may [localize](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#localizing-notifications) your notification when sending it to your users:

```php
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->notify((new InvoicePaid($invoice))->locale($user->locale));
}
```

Also, be sure that you have all translations for any locale available for your user